# "undefined function defexception" Error on Elixir app compilation

Tags: erlang, elixir

While compiling one app, i am getting below error

```
==> dynamo
Compiled lib/dynamo/base.ex
Compiled lib/dynamo/connection/behaviour.ex

== Compilation error on file lib/dynamo/connection/query_parser.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/dynamo/connection/query_parser.ex:2: undefined function defexception/2
(elixir) src/elixir.erl:188: :elixir.quoted_to_erl/3
(stdlib) erl_eval.erl:657: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
(elixir) src/elixir.erl:156: :elixir.erl_eval/2

could not compile dependency dynamo, mix compile failed. You can recompile this dependency with
`mix deps.compile dynamo` or update it with `mix deps.update dynamo`
```

but not able to understand the problem. Version details are show below that i am using,

```
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.1] 
Interactive Elixir (0.14.1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Dynamo is using an incompatible Elixir version. Open up the mix.exs file inside the deps/dynamo checkout in your repository and see the closest version Dynamo was running against.

Also note Dynamo is no in active development, you will likely have better luck with [Phoenix](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix).